# Get-EC2Instance You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

When I try the command "Get-EC2Instance" I get the error "You are not authorized to perform this operation.".

I am an admin and other commands work fine. My admin policy looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "*",
          "Resource": "*"
      }
  ]
```

}

I would have thought this would give me access to EC2 as well?

Answer (score 2):

Debugging AWS PowerShell cmdlets is usually easy.

Verify that you have PowerShell setup with AWS credentials

```
Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail
```

Do you see one or more profiles? If not then you do not have your credentials setup correctly. Follow this document: [Using AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html)

One of the profiles will have the name `default`. If you do not have a default profile, then you can either set one up, or you will need to specify the profile name `-ProfileName` each time you run a command. The document link above explains more. The command to set a default profile:

`Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -ProfileName MyProfileName -Region us-west-2`

Now that you have credentials setup, verify who the IAM user is for the credentials that you are using. First list all the IAM users: `Get-IAMUsers` This will provide you a list of the IAM users for your account. Next get the IAM user `Get-IAMUser`. Verify that the displayed user name is the one that you attached your policy to.

If you are still stuck after getting the above steps working let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
As I wrote, other commands work fine, IAM/S3 stuff for example, so my profile and connection is fine. It is only EC2 that is a problem...

Comment: Did you actually test my steps above or just assume that these steps are not necessary because other commands work? I don't have a crystal ball. You need to provide details if you want anyone to help you. My guess is that you are using credentials that do not have your policy attached.

Comment: Given that I can create and delete IAM users in our AWS environment, I think it is reasonably safe to say that I am connected to our environment, so no, I didn't try your suggestion as that is necessary to connect in the first place.
And as I said, other commands work...